# Converting Evernote ENML to HTML using C#/.net for viewing in a web view

Tags: c#, html, .net, offline, evernote

Is there a .net or C# library to convert an ENML note with its associated resources to html for viewing?

This is needed for **offline** viewing of a local note database synced from Evernote using the Evernote sync protocol. It contains the raw ENML plus attachments for all notes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about one for C#, but there is one for Obj-C that might be trivial to convert.

https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-ios/commit/9c616ddd2cd7c9ea8ff034cc23e7356859f3fcde

Hope that helps.